# SSRS duplicate row in a group when exporting to excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I created a ssrs report that is computing for the total income of a business. The report generates properly when viewed from the reportserver, but when it is exported to excel, the first data in a row group is duplicating. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Do you have any sample illustration/capture for this scenario? there are plenty kind of duplication and what may cause them, if you have grouping on your data and the duplication is on certain group of data, Have you tried remove the grouping and make the grouping again

Comment: Thanks for the reply, solved the problem by recreating the groupings. It seems that I did not properly grouped the data the first time.